# Creating table from query results in empty table on first run

Tags: google-bigquery

When I use the `bq` command line tool to save the results of a query to a table, the table is created, but no data is saved into the table.

I have a few other queries set up the same way that work fine, but for some reason this one does not work.

This is the script I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DATE=`date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" yesterday 00:00' +%Y%m%d`
/usr/bin/bq --nouse_gce_service_account --headless --format none query --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table example.table_$DATE --replace 'select * from example.table_source'
```

It creates the table `example.table_20180827` with all the correct column definitions, but fails to fill the data. A second run of the script does actually fill the data. I don't get any errors.

I see the job/query in the BigQuery UI and it looks fine:

```
Job ID  ****:US.bqjob_***_***_1
Creation Time   Aug 28, 2018, 6:00:04 AM
Start Time  Aug 28, 2018, 6:00:07 AM
End Time    Aug 28, 2018, 6:00:22 AM
User    **@**.com
Bytes Processed 7.70 GB
Bytes Billed    7.71 GB
Slot Time (ms)  854 K
Query Priority  Interactive
Destination Table   ****
Write Preference    Overwrite table
Use Legacy SQL  false
```

It even charges me for all the data.

The other odd thing is that this doesn't happen when I run the script manually. My first thought was that this was an issue with the script being run via crontab (environment issues, etc). However, if I set the job to run every minute (* * * * *), the job runs fine and fills the table.

The only difference I see between this script and my other scripts is that this one is using `select *` instead of specifying the columns manually. Could that be the cause of the issue?

I should also note that the source table is actually a view. Some of the sub tables are google sheets backed tables. I wouldn't think this would matter, but maybe it does.

Comment: The view definition may be relevant here.  Any chance the view depends on data that isn't created until later in the script flow?

Comment: @shollyman Yeah I thought about that. The query is standalone and not part of any other script's flow. I also verified that none of the tables used are being deleted/recreated at the same time.

Comment: for odd behavior that could be a bug - try posting the problem and job id to https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list

Comment: Without more details, hard to say more.  You could attempt to compare query plans for a populating and non-populating run to see if there's a significant difference (e.g. are you missing rows from inputs, or is a query stage filtering them all)?